# Power BI Dax Aggregation

Tags: powerbi, dax, aggregate, powerbi-desktop

I have a formula that I'm using to calculate the remainder between the Singles Sold and the Singles per Box. The current "Singles Sold" measure is a sum of the Singles Sold column in the invoice table, but the calculation is "overcounting" the singles by counting all of them even when the total is greater than the singles per box.

```
[Singles Sold] = sum('[ INVOICE'[SINGLES_SOLD])
```

My formula to calculate the remainder is shown below. It works at the invoice level but the visual will not aggregate the sum of _Adj Singles Sold at the sales company level. I've tried adding the RELATED function but that isn't working. Any thoughts?

```
_Adj Singles Sold = 

VAR Singles_Per_Box = MAX('Product'[Singles per Box]) 
VAR Singles_Sold =  [Singles Sold] 
RETURN
    IF(Singles_Sold < Singles_Per_Box,
        Singles_Sold,
        if(Singles_Per_Box <> 0, 
        MOD(Singles_Sold, Singles_Per_Box),
         0)
    )
```

Here are the related tables in the dataset:

#### Invoice Fact Table

| Inv # | Product ID | Company ID | Singles Sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | P*1 | A*1 | 4 |
| 456 | P*2 | B*1 | 6 |
| 789 | P*3 | G*1 | 7 |

#### Product Dimension Table

| Product ID | Singles per Box |
| --- | --- |
| P*1 | 8 |
| P*2 | 4 |
| P*3 | 4 |

#### Company Dimension Table

| Company ID | Company |
| --- | --- |
| A*1 | Alpha |
| B*1 | Beta |
| G*1 | Gamma |

#### Current Output

| Company | _Adj Singles Sold | Singles Sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | 151 | 1,951 |
| Beta | 68 | 1,268 |
| Gamma | 180 | 1,080 |
| **Total** | **220** | **4,299** |

#### Desired Output

| Company | _Adj Singles Sold | Singles Sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | 1,900 | 1,951 |
| Beta | 1,200 | 1,268 |
| Gamma | 1,000 | 1,080 |
| **Total** | **4,100** | **4,299** |

Comment: Since MOD() Returns the remainder after a number is divided by a divisor, could you return singles box minus _Adj Singles Sold

Comment: That doesn't work for this. I was thinking a SUMX would help solve my problem, but the result ends up with the same value as the Singles Sold.